# PyCharm error - Error loading project: Cannot load facet Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, jetbrains-ide

[image]

I have fresh installed Python and PyCharm and am unable to run some Python files in PyCharm as this error is displayed immediately when loading up the project. I have no idea what the problem could be as the only other times this seems to appear is when trying to interpret Python in IntelliJ using a plugin, or when trying to run some other facet in PyCharm. Unknown facet Python in a Python IDE has stumped me.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the error messages as text. Consider [these reasons and guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557).

Comment: This is a python environment issue in your IDE. Please try out steps from this blog:
https://blog.softhints.com/intellij-idea-error-loading-project-cannot-load-facet-python/

Answer (score 6):

PyCharm and Python plugin store interpreter settings differently (the latter stores them as a facet).

PyCharm does not know anything about Python facet since it does not use it (and even does not have in the distributive).

Solution is to use either IntelliJ IDEA with Python plugin or PyCharm. Before using in PyCharm, please remove `.idea` inside the project to drop the facet.

Comment: I could also instruct PyCharm to ignore the "Python" facet. Seems to work fine.

Comment: Deleting or ignoring doesn't work for me. I also don't understand from this answer what the problem actually is

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was trying to open a non-Python folder with Pycharm.

Opening with Clion seems to work, as this really was a C++ project.

The error message should be much clearer, and the folder really should open. After all they are just files.